# User Input is not storing correctly in array

Tags: javascript

Im given the task of storing 10 elements in an Array, then I have to add all of those elements.

My problem comes at the time of storing each individual element in the array. 
When I set the length of the for loop as numbers.length it fills the array with the first number that was inputted, and if I set the length to 10, it only places the value in the index[0] and leaves the others as undefined.

```
var numbers = new Array();
function addnew() {
var un = document.getElementById('userNumber').value;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     numbers.push(" " + un[i]);
}

console.log(numbers);
document.getElementById('elements').innerHTML = numbers;
```

The output that is expected is a list that shows the values entered by the user inputs into the array (length of 10) and the sum of those values.
What it's actually showing is the first number inputted followed by undefined till it reaches the maximum length which is 10.

Comment: can you provide example expected output and input

Comment: How do distinguish in input `12` between `1` + `2` and just `12`?

Comment: @RyanWilson Actually `un` is string of `userNumber.value`, so if input is `123` then `un[2]` would be `3`

Comment: At beginning your `numbers.length` is 0. I think you should do `un.length`

Comment: @Justinas good call, I missed the `.value` on the end, well the problem is you are expecting each input to have 10 characters as you are pushing into your array, and that is not the case everytime, say I input 1 as the UserNumber, then it keeps iterating 9 more times, there are not 9 more characters in the input value, so you get "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

it's because `un` string length is 1 as it not saved completely

```
var numbers = new Array();
function addnew() {
var un = '123';

for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(10,un.length); i++) {
     numbers.push(" " + un[i]);
}

console.log(numbers);
document.getElementById('elements').innerHTML = numbers;
}


}
```

Comment: Why it's not saved completely and why it's length is 1 when you enter `123456`?

Comment: may it's on text Changed callback which call function as soon first character entered

Answer (score 0):

If your user is entering a space inbetween each number, you can just split that one string into an array.

```
numbers = un.split(" ");
```

numbers now contains an array of strings.

Then convert the strings to numbers, so you can get the sum.

```
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = Number(numbers[i]);
}
```

And then this will give you the sum.

```
sumOfNumbers = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(sumOfNumbers);
```

```js
un = "1 2 3 12";
numbers = un.split(" ");
console.log(numbers);
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = Number(numbers[i]);
}
console.log(numbers);
sumOfNumbers = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log("sum is " + sumOfNumbers);
```

Answer (score -1):

At beginning your `numbers.length` is 0. I think you should do `un.length`

```js
function addnew() {
  var numbers = [];
  var un = document.getElementById('userNumber').value;

  for (var i = 0; i < un.length; i++) {
       numbers.push(" " + un[i]);
  }

  console.log(numbers);
  document.getElementById('elements').innerHTML = numbers;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userNumber" onChange="addnew()"/>

<span id="elements"></span>
```